# How can I find the calling routine for a symbol in case of a linker error "undefined reference"?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I have a problem linking an application for an embedded target. I'm developing on a windows box using Min-GW for an ARM9 target that runs under Linux.
Actually I'm switching from static linking to dynamic linking with .so-libraries to save memory space.
I get the error message

```
libT3Printer.so: undefined reference to `__ASSERT'
```

I checked all the sources for the lib and I have no idea where this function could be called. Is there any possibility to find out, who (which source file or function) could be the caller of the missing function?

Comment: On my Mac, the linker prints out a list of callers underneath the "undefined reference" error message. Maybe you could try a different linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference is probably being hidden by a macro.  If you run the compiler with the -E option to generate predecessor output you might have a better chance of tracking it down.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add definition **NDEBUG**.

In C, compiling with NDEBUG defined:

`gcc -DNDEBUG foo.c`

**disables** all calls to **assert()**, and this behavior is identical in C++:

`g++ -DNDEBUG foo.cpp`